# Factor Scores Level 2 in a Multilevel Model

Tags: stata, multilevel-analysis, weighted-regression

My question is twofold and concerns weighting in multilevel models and using factor scores as predictors on level 2.

Here is my problem: I want to estimate (using the meologit command in Stata 13) a multilevel model with a ordered categorical dependent variable. My data are persons (N=34500) nested in zip-codes (N=6348) obtained by using a complex survey design. The range of number of observation within level 2-units is [1-45] meaning I have many zip-codes with just 1 participant and several with 20+ person and some up to 45. The average is about 5 persons per zip-code. I combined the data from the interviews with offical statistics which I want to use as level-2 predictors. For instance, I calculated a factor ARMUT (poverty) consisting of 3 items which are theoretical meaningful. To do so I calculated a weight (1/"obs per zip-code") to take into account the distribution of persons over zip-codes. Hence, using the predict command, my factor has a mean=0 and a SD=1. However, when I use unweighted data (which I would prefer and following the *model based*-approach) to estimate my two-level model, the mean and SD of my level-2 factors are obviously slightly off.

OK, now my questions:

1. Do you think it is a good idea to calculate a weight to take into account the size of level-2 units in my factor analysis? If not my problem is solved, but I need a good argument for that approach.
2. How do you think about using weights in multivariate regressions (multilevel modeling in my case)?

Any advice would be highly appreciated.